# Order data.frame by row values in a column and by column values in a row in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have six cockatiel birds, `"Beefy", "Scoundrel", "Baston", "Mattdamon", "Jesus", and "Hulkhogan"`. These birds poo a lot, and in a lot of different locations. I've decided to track where and how often this occurs over the last 2 weeks, and I'm trying to figure out where these little devils pooed the most today.

```
mydata <- data.frame(Dates = structure(c(16656, 16657, 16658, 16659,
                                         16660, 16661, 16662, 16663,
                                         16664, 16665, 16666, 16667,
                                         16668, 16669 
                                         ), 
                                       class = "Date"), 
                     PooLoc1 = sample(1:40, 7),
                     PooLoc2 = sample(1:10, 7),
                     PooLoc3 = sample(1:10, 7),
                     PooLoc4 = sample(1:30, 7),
                     PooLoc5 = sample(1:20, 7),
                     PooLoc6 = sample(1:70, 7)
)

head(mydata)
     Dates PooLoc1 PooLoc2 PooLoc3 PooLoc4 PooLoc5 PooLoc6
2015-08-09      24       3       9       1      16      45
2015-08-10      39       2       2      12      12       2
2015-08-11      14       7       6       5      19       4
2015-08-12      26       9       8      27       3      64
2015-08-13      20       4       1      15      20      48
2015-08-14       9       1       4       8       8      61
```

I can order `mydata` rows by column date to easily find today's poos like so:

```
mydata <- mydata[order(mydata[["Dates"]], decreasing = TRUE), ]
```

But how do I order the columns by the values obtained on today's date so that I can quickly look at the top left of `mydata` and find the answer to my question? Can you do it in one line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this may be what you want.  We just order the columns (second to end) by the first row.

```
mydata[, c(1, order(mydata[1, -1], decreasing = TRUE) + 1)]
#        Dates PooLoc6 PooLoc1 PooLoc4 PooLoc5 PooLoc3 PooLoc2
# 6 2015-08-14      61       9       8       8       4       1
# 5 2015-08-13      48      20      15      20       1       4
# 4 2015-08-12      64      26      27       3       8       9
# 3 2015-08-11       4      14       5      19       6       7
# 2 2015-08-10       2      39      12      12       2       2
# 1 2015-08-09      45      24       1      16       9       3
```

Now the top left value has the highest value for today's date.

And per the request in the comments, we can order the rows and columns in one call with

```
mydata[
    order(mydata$Dates, decreasing = TRUE), 
    c(1, order(mydata[1, -1], decreasing = TRUE) + 1)
]
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to do your column sorting and the date sorting in one line?

Comment: Yes, just put your date order call on the left side of the comma and the column order on the right, like this - `mydata[order(mydata$Dates, decreasing = TRUE), c(1, order(mydata[1, -1], decreasing = TRUE) + 1)]`